# WPF Xceed PropertyGrid showing "Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.Item" instead of the real DisplayName

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, propertygrid, xceed

I'm trying to use Xceed PropertyGrid to show dropdown with hardcoded string values.
Instead of showing the items as the strings I assign as the `IItemSource`, PropertyGrid showing: "Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.Item" for each item in the dropdown.
When I select an object, the desired string is showing as the chosen item.

This is the dropdown items I see:

[image]

And when I choose an item, I can see it the way I want it to appear as the dropdown items as well:

[image]

**My code:**

XAML:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding MySettingsWrapper}" AutoGenerateProperties="True">
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

C#:

```
[Serializable]
public class SettingsWrapper
{
    [LocalizedCategory("SettingsViewCategoryHardware")]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("SettingsViewLblSelectPrinter")]
    [ItemsSource(typeof(PrintersItemSource))]
    public string SelectedPrinter { get; set; }

    public class PrintersItemSource : IItemsSource
    {
        public ItemCollection GetValues()
        {
            var printers = new ItemCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                printers.Add("Option - " + i);
            }

            return printers;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Caliburn.Micro, BTW.

I've tried several things and I'm out of ideas.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public ItemCollection GetValues()
{
    var printers = new ItemCollection();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        string entry = "Option - " + i;
        printers.Add(entry, entry);
    }

    return printers;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, both should work as your way does a "ToString()" of your object in the "Add" function. So it's a template issue then. When a template isn't set or found for a given type, it prints the "ToString()" of the bound object. In your case, "Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.Item". It's working fine on my side btw.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the toString() fallback in case no `DisplayName` parameter was sent.. Don't know what I'm doing wrong though..

Comment: Is it possible for you to send me a quick and dirty simple Visual Studio solution in which the issue happens? So that way, I'll be able to test it on my side.