# Xceed propertygrid not showing DisplayName

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, xceed

I am using Xceed propertygrid in my project, and for some reason when I open the dropdown of the property it is showing "Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.Item"
instead of the items i inserted.
I am sure it is because the `toString()` method is called, i just can't figure out why..
I saw this question 
[WPF Xceed PropertyGrid showing "Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.Item" instead of the real DisplayName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836989/wpf-xceed-propertygrid-showing-xceed-wpf-toolkit-propertygrid-attributes-item)
, this is exactly my problem but it doesn't seem that he got a solution. I have tried many attempts solution but non worked.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `ToString` method to show whatever property you wanted, for example lets say we have the following class as a `SelectedObject` for your `propertyGrid` control:

```
public class Company
{
    [Category("Main")]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [Description("Property description")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Category("Main")]
    [DisplayName("Type")]
    [Description("Property description")]
    public String Type { get; set; }
    [Category("Main")]
    [DisplayName("Something")]
    [Description("Property description")]
    public bool Something { get; set; }
    [Category("Main")]
    [DisplayName("Director")]
    [Description("Property description")]
    [ItemsSource(typeof(EmployeList))]
    public Employe Director { get; set; }
}
```

the collection should be defined as follow

```
 public class EmployeList : IItemsSource
{
    public Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.ItemCollection GetValues()
    {
        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.ItemCollection employe = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.ItemCollection();
        employe.Add(new Employe()
        {
            Name = "Name1",
            Rank = "Rank1",
            Age=40,
        }); employe.Add(new Employe()
        {
            Name = "Name2",
            Rank = "Rank2",
            Age=40,
        }); employe.Add(new Employe()
        {
            Name = "Name3",
            Rank = "Rank3",
            Age=40,
        });
        return employe;
    }
}
```

and the `Employe` class should override the `Tostring` method

```
  public class Employe
{        
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Rank { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid  Name="pg"  SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedCompany}" AutoGenerateProperties="True" >                
    </xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

and the result is what you are looking for

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already tried this solution, the problem is that once entered into the ItemCollection, a new Item class is constructed and entered into the collection. So the ToString function called is still the Item's one.